# Classical mechanics principle of least action

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

I don't understand here what does the book mean by expanding in terms of $\delta{q}$ and $\delta{\dot{q}}$ can someone explain that part.
I don't understand how did he get that final step?

> The change in $S$ when $q$ is replaced by $q + \delta q$ is 
>   $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q + \delta q , \dot{q} + \delta \dot{q}, t) dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot{q}, t) dt.$$ When this difference is expanded in powers of $\delta q$ and $\delta \dot{q}$ in the integrand, the leading terms are of the first order. The necessary condition for $S$ to have a minimum is that these terms (called the *first variation*, or simply the *variation*, of the integral) should be zero. Thus the principle of least action may be written in the form $$\delta S = \delta \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot{q}, t) dt = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

The author means "write out a power series expansion (e.g. Taylor series) for the difference $L(q+\delta q,\dot{q}+\delta\dot{q},t)-L(q,\dot{q},t)$. The terms with $q$ or $\dot q$ likely cancel in this difference, so that the power series is written in terms of $\delta q$ and $\delta\dot{q}$, though without knowing what Lagrangian you are using, it is difficult to say for certain that the $q$ and $\dot{q}$ terms cancel.

Comment: how come will they cancel ?

Comment: can you please explicitly show it to me ?

Comment: @Illustionist What Lagrangian density are you using?